# Finding the longest path in a network based on vector edge weights

Tags: algorithm, networkx, graph-theory, geopandas, shapely

I have this road network with elevation data for every `POINT` and a calculated grade value for every `LINESTRING`:
[image: network]

> **Note:** points plotted on graph are my own they do not represent the nodes on the graph which include all the missing endpoints

I have converted it to a networkx `MultiGraph` which I have generated from a `GeoPandasDataframe`:

```
seg_df = pd.DataFrame(
{'grade': grades})
seg_grade = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    seg_df, geometry=new_seg_list)
network = momepy.gdf_to_nx(seg_grade, approach='primal')
```

in the code above `grades` is a list of integer grade values and new_seg_list is a list of `LINESTRING` objects which match with the indices of the grade list ex:

> the grade of `new_seg_list[0]` = `grades[0]`

this grade value is the `elevation_change` from `LINESTRING.coords[0]` to `LINESTRING.coords[-1]` divided by the length of the `LINESTRING`.

My network object has the correct node and edge values so that functions such as

```
nx.shortest_path(G=Gr, source=start_node, target=end_node, weight='length')
```

works correctly. How do I find the longest path (only use each edge once) that is entirely downhill (negative grade from `LINESTRING.coords[0]` to `LINESTRING.coords[-1]`)?

The main difficulties that I'm having are the fact that the `grade` values are from the start vertex to the end vertex of each `LINESTRING` which makes it hard to translate into the `networkx` graph. I still have the elevation data for each node so if there is some way to calculate this grade as paths are tested that might be the best way

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example of your graph? So that we can try to work on it.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco How would I provide a minimal example of the network? I have the networkx object but it's just a massive dataframe of nodes and edges

Comment: Just build a smaller one with some relevant features..

Comment: @RiccardoBucco sure ill try

Answer (score 0):

So, in general [longest path problem is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). However, it is solvable in linear time when the graph is a directed acyclic graph (DAG).

For your case, I don't fully understand the problem, but perhaps you can build a DAG like this to produce your desired output:

- Only have an edge between nodes that are on different elevations, and make the direction from the one higher to lower.

So then you'd have a DAG, where there are edges from higher `POINT`s to lower `POINT`s, and there you can find the longest path using [networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path.html) readily available in `networkx`.

Comment: While attempting to try this just with the length weight to see if it works I have `short = nx.dag_longest_path(G=Gr.to_directed(), weight='length')` however my graph contains a cycle since it is a street map (https://i.imgur.com/i9NFgKY.png). How would I do this problem with the cycles? or how would I eliminate the cycles while still getting an accurate result? The nodes are all at different elevations by the way so I would just have to change the direction from high to low somehow in networkx

Comment: In the way I described it's not possible to have cycles, since you always go from high elevation to low elevation. I think you haven't set up a DAG yet right? Calling `to_directed()` on an undirected graph will just return a directed graph with undirected edges converted to two edges going both ways, so you'll have many many cycles.

Comment: So I would have to loop through each point and find all paths for that point that only go down in elevation and not include it if that path is already included in another found path? Is there a way to find all of these paths based on node weights in networkx? or would i have to generate this new DAG manually? Would I have multiple networks since not all of the down in elevation paths would be connected?